# Modifying abbreviations in Zencoding

Tags: jquery, notepad++, emmet

I use notepad++ with Zen Coding.

I would like to add a new abbreviation

```
script:jquery17
```

which does the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re JS version of Zen Coding (downloaded from either https://github.com/sergeche/zen-coding/downloads or http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/list), you need to open `Zen Coding.js` file located in NppScripting/includes directory of downloaded archive. There is `zen_settings` variable on top of it, which describes all available abbreviations and snippets, and add your own.

If you’re using Python version (downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/) you have to find `zen_settings.py` file in it.

For more info on how to add new elements and snippets read this tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/21/zen-coding-a-new-way-to-write-html-code/

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the JS version of NppScripting without Zen Coding, see https://web.archive.org/web/20121025032526/http://www.softwarecanoe.de/data/nppscripting.zip . Some of the APIs of Notepad++ seem to be available at https://code.google.com/p/hxnpp/source/browse/trunk/programs/Notepad%2B%2B/plugins/haxe/hxnpp/hxnpp/?r=2